# Is there a way to write `regex` without repeating some parts?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match `Internet.` or `Internet` at the end of string.

I can write:

```
$str =~ m/Internet\.|Internet$/
```

Is there a way to write `regex` without repeating `Internet`?

Comment: Their current regex allows _either_ `Internet.` or `Internet<end of string>`, so `/Internet\.?$/` wouldn't work because it wouldn't match e.g. `Internet. And more.` even though it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use parens to group things together, and the pipe works locally within the group.

This means, you can turn `ab|ac` into `a(b|c)`. Note that this also automatically creates a capturing group<sup>1</sup>; if you don't want that, you can use `a(?:b|c)`.

So, in your case, you could write<sup>2</sup>:

```perl
$str =~ /Internet(\.|$)/
```

(Or `/Internet(?:\.|$)/` to use a non-capturing group, but it seems it doesn't matter here.)

---

<sub>**1:** This means that the contents of the matched group would go into `$1` (or `$2`, etc. depending the how-many-th group it is), so with `a(b|c)` you would get either `b` or `c` in `$1`.</sub>

<sub>**2:** I removed the `m` because it is the default mode for pattern matching anyway.</sub>

<sub>**Side note:** As mentioned by commenter JvdV below, depending on your use case you may also consider adding a word boundary before the word `Internet`. Then, it would only match something like `The Internet.` or `(Internet.)` but not `IIIIInternet.`. You would do this using `\b`, e.g. `/\bInternet(\.|$)/`</sub>

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `$` doesn't match (just) the end of the string. You want `\z` for that.

---

`(?:...)` can be used as parentheses are used in mathematics. This enables us to factor out the common prefix as follows:

```
/Internet(?:\.|\z)/
```

---

In general, we can use interpolation or `DEFINE`.

For example, let's look at the following match which uses a long repeated pattern we can't simply factor out:

```
/ ^ [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* (?: \. [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* )* \z /x
```

Using interpolation:

```
my $ident = qr/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/;
/ ^ $ident (?: \. $ident )* \z /x
```

Using `DEFINE` (better):

```
/
   ^ (?&IDENT) (?: \. (?&IDENT) )* \z

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<IDENT> [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* )
   )
/x
```

There's still repetition, but instead of repeating a complex pattern, we are repeating a simple word, and spelling errors will result in a fatal error rather than potentially-subtle misbehaviour.

Comment: Why is using `DEFINE` "_better_" -- because there is no need for an extra variable then, or are there yet other reasons?  (efficiency?)

Comment: @zdim, Because the other way compiles the pattern, stringifies it, then recompiles it. (Only if the entire pattern is a var is stringification and recompilation avoided.) And of course, it has to check if `$ident` changed if you call the match in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input, it may come in the Start/middle/end of the content. So it would be better to use the below code to avoid case:

```
$str =~ m/[Ii]nternet(\.|$)/
or
$str =~ m/Internet(\.|$)/i
```

Also, if you want to store in the group, use parenthesis.